# Grab information from multiple cells and display it in one cell based on specific text match

Tags: excel, google-sheets, lookup-tables

I'm at my wits end. What formula should I even go for? Can I achieve what I'm trying to do in Google Sheets?

I have attached a picture of a mockup what I'm trying to do.

Basically I have 2 tables. Let us call them "Calendar" - TABLE A and "Schedule" TABLE B.

TABLE A - I mark manually an event and a name or names behind it.

TABLE B - Is the table I'm trying to create a formula for. In the picture colored green is where the formula bit should be. Basically trying to search TABLE A and match the Date (19 July) with the name (Mary)

So in text the formula matches TABLE A information of 19 July and every cell with Mary and displays it in TABLE B, under the fields Mary and 19 July displays what TABLE A had going for him.

Cool if I could simply trim the end result and remove other names, so if there was "Mary and Richard", it would know to remove those names from the fields.

So basically display every cell with "Mary" in TABLE A, and display it in TABLE B under one cell.

[image: Picture of what I'm trying to accomplish]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Formulas will be exceedingly complex, and require helper columns.  VBA would be the way to go; parsing each cell in Table A into users, tasks and date; then creating (or adding to) your results table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option with a helper sheet.

Let's say your data is on a sheet called `Data`, range `Data!A1:AB21`:

[image]

Create a helper sheet called `Formula`:

[image]

Cell `B2` gets the headers from the Data sheet:

```
={Data!A1:AB1}
```

Cells `A2:A5` have the fixed names, Mark, John, Richard, Tom.

This formula goes in **EVERY** cell within the range `B2:AC5` (drag down and drag across):

```
=arrayformula(iferror(textjoin(",",1,trim(regexreplace(filter(Data!A:A,regexmatch(Data!A:A,$A2)),textjoin("|",1,$A$2:$A$5),))),))
```

[image]

A final Sheet called 'Results' has this in cell `A1`:

```
=transpose(Formula!A:AC)
```

[image]

It's not as elegant as having an arrayformula in a single cell on the `Formula` sheet, but it does work once you've set the data range and dragged the formula down and across.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain your results using Power Query provided that:

- There is a reproducible method of obtaining the **Names**

  - In your example, each name is a single word, and they all occur together at the end of an activity substring
  - Multi-name words will require a different algorithm to extract.

To use Power Query *(available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365)*

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="TableA"]}[Content],

//need to hard code list of names
    names = {"Mary","John","Richard","Tom"},

//Type all as text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, Text.Type})),

//Unpivot to => a two column list
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {}, "Dates", "Value"),

//Extract the names
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Columns", "Names", each List.Intersect({Text.Split([Value]," "),names})),

//Extract the Activities
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Activity", each Text.Start([Value],Text.PositionOf([Value],[Names]{0})-1)),

//Remove unneeded column
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Value"}),

//Expand the names to => single row for each name/date
    #"Expanded Names" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Names"),

//Group by Date and Name
// Aggregate the activites
    grouped = Table.Group(#"Expanded Names",{"Dates","Names"},{
        {"Activities", each Text.Combine([Activity],", "), type text}
    }),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(grouped, List.Distinct(grouped[Names]), "Names", "Activities"),

//reArrange columns to desired order
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Pivoted Column",List.Combine({{"Dates"}, names}))

in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

**Table A**
[image]

**Table B**
[image]